# Save a Properties.Resources from Code - C# .NET CORE 5.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, resources, .net-5

I have these Resources

[image: Resources]

I use this code to get the value of the resource and works

`Properties.Resources.defaultLanguage`

How can i update this value from code ?
It's readOnly so the following code doesn't work

`Properties.Resources.defaultLanguage = "TEST"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i update this value from code ?

You don't; use the `Impostazioni` (Settings) one instead